# CSS image slider (images don't stay in the same position)?

Tags: html, css

I have made a small CSS image slider for my webpage, but I have a few issues with my images (the images in the slider). The images positions differ on the screen (although I have made sure the images were the same size before upload).

The first image of the slider is too high (as there is no gap between the header and the image). The second image works fine, third image is lower than the second and first image? My webpage can be seen at codepen.io (http://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/dGdqvx)

```
@keyframes slider {

 0% {
   left: 0;
   }

 20% {
    left: 0;
    }

 25% {
    left: -100%;
    }

 45% {
    left: -100%;
    }

 50% {
   left: -200%;
   }

 70% {
   left: -200%;
   }

 75% {
   left: -300%;
   }

 95% {
   left: -300%;
   }

 100% {
   left: -400%;
     }
   }

 #slider {
 overflow: hidden;
   }

  #slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  }

  #slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slider infinite;

  }
      }
```

Comment: Thank-you for your help :) May I be greedy and ask how to lower the main image (so there is a gap between the image ad the header)? Moreover, once again a big thank-you!!

Comment: Ah sorry for moving my comment on you right before you commented back. I just added a margin to your `#slider` div, is this what you mean?: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjrOjN

Comment: Thank-you alyssums. The webpage is perfect!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Want to approve my answer if it's all good?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `<li>` elements still having `list-style`. It's still not perfect, but I added `list-style: none` to your `<li>` elements holding the images (I also tweaked the image width) and they stay aligned: codepen.io/anon/pen/gPejEJ

```
#slider figure li {
 list-style: none;
}
#slider figure img {
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
}
```